# Store output into a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I have created a calculator using html, javascript, and php to send the information to a database so I can create a pdf from the stored information. The issue I am coming across is that I cannot store any of the output fields into the database so those fields on the pdf are just displaying 0. Here is an example of my some of my code:

Form:

```
<div class="butfix">
    <label style="width: 40%; float: left;">Taxable Wage (Hourly)</label>
    <input class="input-field butfix" style="float: left; width: 8em;" type="text" name="taxable_wage" id="taxable_wage">
</div>

<div class="butfix">
    <label style="width: 40%; float: left;">Average Hours Per Week</label>
    <input class="input-field" style="float: left; width: 8em;" type="text" name="average_hours_per_week" id="average_hours_per_week">
</div>

<div class="butfix" style = "margin-top: 2%;">
    <label style="width: 40%; float: left;">Weekly Taxable Pay</label>
    <output class="input-field" style="float: left; width: 8em;" type="text" name="weekly_taxable_pay" id="weekly_taxable_pay"></output>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var weeklyTaxablePay = document.getElementById("weekly_taxable_pay");

taxableWage.addEventListener("change", calc);
averageHoursPerWeek.addEventListener("change", calc);


function calc() {
weeklyTaxablePay.textContent = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("taxable_wage").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("average_hours_per_week").value)).toFixed(2);
}
```

In the example above I am trying to store the "weekly taxable pay" into the database. After doing some research online I have seen that outputs aren't compatible with databases so one would need to create an input to store the outputs value. I have tried doing this by adding in a hidden input field and giving it the same id and name as the output like so:

```
<input class="input-field" style="float: left; width: 8em;" type="text" name="weekly_taxable_pay" id="weekly_taxable_pay">
```

However when I do this nothing is displayed in the input box upon completion of the equation. I have seen other examples on stackoverflow and tried these however nothing seems to work for me. I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions or knows of any other solutions that may assist me in this situation. I appreciate any input and thank you for your time.

EDIT

Here is some of my php code although I am fairly confident this is not the issue.

Storing info into the database:

```
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

/* Create connection */
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/* Check connection*/
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $taxable_wage = $_POST['taxable_wage'];
    $average_hours_per_week = $_POST['average_hours_per_week'];
    $weekly_taxable_pay = $_POST['weekly_taxable_pay'];

/* sql to insert row into table */
    $sql = "INSERT INTO calculations (taxable_wage, average_hours_per_week, weekly_taxable_pay) VALUES ('$taxable_wage', '$average_hours_per_week', '$weekly_taxable_pay')";
```

Retrieving info from the database:

```
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";/* Put your password */
$dbname = "***";/* Put your database name */

/* Create connection */
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
/* Check connection*/
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
}
  $output = '';  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM calculations ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {       
  $output .= '
           <tr>  
                      <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                      <td>'.$row["taxable_wage"].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>          
                      <th width="30%">Email</th>  
                      <td>'.$row["average_hours_per_week"].'</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>   
                      <th width="30%">Taxable Wage (Hourly)</th>
                      <td>'.$row["weekly_taxable_pay"].'</td> 
            </tr>
                  ';  
  }  
  return $output;
```

After this I have the code to create the pdf and which is definitely working the way it should.

Comment: Where is your php code? please add more code.

Comment: @twinaholic I have added the relevant php code

Comment: After you create your INSERT query, you never run it.

Comment: why do you return instead of echo?

Comment: @Cat the INSERT query is being run right after that I just didn't include that part because I can see for sure that the "inputs" are being added to the database just not any of the "outputs" which is my main issue, sorry I may not have made that clear in my post.

Comment: @twinaholic I use "return" instead of "echo" because the "return" is part of the "creating a pdf" part of my program which I know is working fine I am just unable to store any of the "output" math equation results into the database.

Comment: In the part where you are storing the information to db, I do not see where you are running the sql query. Also, are you getting any errors if any?

Comment: @twinaholic The sql query is run right after the code above and no I do not see any errors.

Comment: is <output class="input-field" style="float: left; width: 8em;" type="text" name="weekly_taxable_pay" id="weekly_taxable_pay"></output> and <input class="input-field" style="float: left; width: 8em;" type="text" name="weekly_taxable_pay" id="weekly_taxable_pay"> on the same page? if so, they will need unique id's

Comment: @Cat I have tried that as well. I feel like I may be way overthinking this and confusing myself at this point haha. I am just trying to get the "weekly taxable pay output" value to attach to the new "weekly taxable pay input" so that I can then send that to the database.